# Point inside rectangle given sides and center

Tags: c++, geometry, rectangles

I'm given rectangle by it's height(*h*) and width(*w*), and it's center *O(x0,y0)*. I need to calculate if given point A(x,y) is inside that rectangle. It is parallel to x and y axis. All values are real.

I came up with following test but for some reason website on which I'm testing the code is not working for all examples. Could someone point me in the right direction.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    long x,y,x0,y0,r,h,w;
    scanf("%ld",&x);
    scanf("%ld",&y);
    scanf("%ld",&x0);
    scanf("%ld",&y0);
    scanf("%ld",&h);
    scanf("%ld",&w);
    if((x0+w/2.0>=x)&&(x0-w/2.0<=x)&&(y0+h/2.0>=y)&&(y0-h/2.0<=y))
        printf("inside a rectangle");
    else
        printf("outside a rectangle");
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `3/2 == 1` using *long*, not `1.5`, try with *double* (and `%lf`)

Comment: @RingØ there are no float divisions in OP's code

Comment: It's C/C++. Thanks Ring I'll try

Comment: @AnttiHaapala You mean "no *integer* division", right the `2.0` , but what if user enter decimals during input?

Comment: There is hardly any C++ in this, it's almost only C. Get rid of `scanf` and use `std::cin`.

Comment: On the edge is inside. And they should be real values, my bad. Range is not stated, but its not big and memory is not a problem. 64MB are given

Comment: *"I need to get used to using scanf because of competitions"* - Those competitions obviously keep you from learning how to write good C++. If I were you, I'd just quit those terrible "competitions" and move on.

Comment: @ChristianHackl.: Yes I will say the same thing. Have you ever seen the code they write - I mean let alone readablilty - those just check the algorithm sense. And all the c++ coder adds the header `bits/stdc++.h`. And then they always get a happy path input - so no error checking needed. It is completely completely different from writing a good software or bulletproofing the code. You said it right.

Comment: @ĐumićBranislav: That's something between an urban legend and premature optimisation. The truth is that where the difference *actually* exists and matters, even `printf` et al would likely be too slow and you'd have to switch to non-portable solutions like memory-mapped files. Your comment reinforces my firm belief that "coding competitions" foster a programming philosophy incompatible with good engineering practices.

Comment: I just say what I was said. Ill delete those two comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### After OP's Edit:

The rectangle's side are parallel to x axis and y-axis. Then also it is possible to get the co-ordinates and apply the below mentioned algorithm.

```
Centre -- (x0,y0)
A -- (x0-w/2,y0-h/2)
B -- (x0-w/2.y0+h/2)
C -- (x0+w/2,y0+h/2)
D -- (x0+w/2,y0-h/2)
```

So all you have to do is, Apply the algorithms provided below.

**More simply we can do this,**

```
if( 2*x <= 2*x0+w && 2*x >= 2*x0-w && 2*y <= 2*y0+h && 2*y >= 2*y0-h)
// it's inside
```

---

#### Before OP's edit

Your logic is wrong. It may say a point inside rectangle to be outside of it.
(For any rectangle this is wrong - OP didn't mention the condition of being sides parallel to x-y axes)

There is a simple way and cleaner way to do this for rectangle. Find the Area of the rectangle.

Suppose it's `A`.

Now if the point `P` lies inside `ABCD` then

```
area of PAB+PBC+PCD+PDA = A
```

For better thing do this with ,

```
AB.Bc+BC.CD+CD.DA+DA.AB = 2*AB*BC
```

or even better make a square of both side

```
LHS^2 = 4*AB^2*BC^2
```

Now you will just multiply and check it. One drawback of this solution is for large values of `side length` you have a chance of overflow.

Another method would be to consider the projections.

If point is inside of the rectangle then the projection of the corner of rectangle to point, on two of it's side must be less than the corresponding sides. You can check the projection length using dot products.

For example if `P` is the point and `ABCD` is rectangle check,

if `AP`'s projection on `AB` has greater than zero length but less than the length of `AB`. Check the same with `BC` and `BP` and check if length is greater than zero and less than `BC` or not.

This two condition makes sure that your point lies inside the rectangle.

Comment: I'm not sure this makes my life easier. I know only center of rectangle and lengths of it's sides. I'm not sure how to implement this with that data.

Comment: @ĐumićBranislav.: But with one centre and 2 side lengths you can have multiple rectangle. How do you decide which rectangle is it?

Comment: What do you mean multiple of them? It's one rectangle. Center is diagonal intersection.

Comment: @ĐumićBranislav.; Correct me if I am wrong but you can always get different rectangles with same diagonal intersection. Think this way, you have decided one set of intersecting diagonals. Now rotate the diagonals by 30 degree and join the sides. You will get another rectangle with same side lenghts and diagonal interection.

Comment: Rectangle is parallel to x and y axis. Also it has 2 h and 2 w sides. Parallel sides are the same length. Isn't that what rectangle is?

Comment: @ĐumićBranislav.: A rectangle can be also non-parallel to x and y - axis.  If it is rotated then it;s also a rectangle. It doesn't depend on the orientation You can check the definition. If question says that they are parallel to x axis the it's different thing but rectangle can be anything following the criteria of rectangle. Dioesn;t depend on if their sides are parallel to `x` or `y` axis.

Comment: Its parallel for this problem i have. My bad

Comment: @ĐumićBranislav.: Both of them can be used. This is generalized algorithm for convex polygons.(2nd one). So these are applicable. I will modify my answer.

Comment: But I dont understand. I am not given any vertices of this rectangle. It's just diagonal intersection and side lengths. Can you explain symbols in formuals.

Comment: Thanks. Ill give it a shot. Just tell me, whats S in last formula

Comment: @ĐumićBranislav.; Check the answer I have added the simple solution